# Montar um Strobe Light dentro do canvas JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, setinterval

Estou com uma tarefa pra desenvolver pra faculdade mas estou com alguns problemas.

Primeiro deixa eu tentar explicar o que fazer:

Preciso simular um strobe light baseado em algumas cores num selector HTML. O usuário deve escolher o intervalo (ainda não fiz o intervalo, não sei como é). Depois o usuário precisa escolher qual cor ele quer que faça parte do Strobe. Quando clicar no Add Colour essa cor escolhida deve ser listada abaixo do "Colour Order". Quando clicar no Dance Party as cores escolhidas devem começar a piscar no canvas de acordo com o intervalo escolhido.

Até o momento consegui desenvolver isso:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Strobe Light</title>
    <script src="a6.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
   </head>

  <body onload="setUp()">
    <h1>Strobe Light</h1>

    <p>How fast should it flash? Enter a number between 1-15000 ms <input type="text" name="" id="strobeSpeed" value=""></p>

    <p>What colours should flash?
      <select id="colorSelector">
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="purple">Purple</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" id="addColour" name="button">Add Colour</button>
      <button type="button" id="clearColour" name="button">Clear Colour</button>
    </p>

    <p>Colour Order</p>
    <ul id="colourOrder"></ul>

    <button type="button" id="danceParty" name="button">Dance Party!!!!!</button>

    <br>
    <br>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="300" width="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let canvas;
let ctx;

function setUp(){
   canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   let showColour = document.getElementById("colourOrder");

   document.getElementById('addColour').onclick = function(){
     ctx.fillStyle = document.getElementById('colorSelector').value;
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   };

   document.getElementById('clearColour').onclick = function(){
     ctx.fillStyle = "white";
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   };

   document.getElementById('danceParty').onclick = function(){

   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

É preciso criar um array com as cores.

```
let canvas;
let ctx;

function setUp(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let showColour = document.getElementById("colourOrder");
  let colors = [];

  document.getElementById('addColour').onclick = function() {
    colors.push(document.getElementById('colorSelector').value);
  };

  document.getElementById('clearColour').onclick = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  };

  document.getElementById('danceParty').onclick = function() {
    let i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      i++;
      if (i >= colors.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
    }, document.getElementById('strobeSpeed').value);
  };
}
```